# pasar elementos de un archivo txt a una variable en python

Tags: python, lista, txt

tengo una duda que no se como solucionar. Tengo un programa en el que tengo unos numeros de telefono en un archivo txt tal que así.

[image: Aqui vemos unos numeros de telefono, cada uno en una fila diferente.]

bueno pues yo tengo este código:

```
with open("targets.txt") as filetoma:
lectura = filetoma.read()
print(lectura)
```

pero la salida es como en la imagen, cada numero en una linea, sin embargo a mi me interesa hacer una lista con esos numeros tal que así:

> ['619202384', '778562501' etc...]

alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? gracias, PD: si la solución en fácil no me peguen, soy algo nuevo en python.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que has leido completo el contenido del archivo, puedes separar cada línea usando el método `split()`, indicando que el elemento separador es el '\n', o *new line*

```
with open("telefonos.txt", "r") as filetoma:
    lista = filetoma.read().split('\n')
    print(lista)
```

produce una lista de cadenas:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

dado un archivo de entrada

```
ricardo@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ more telefonos.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```